# Were the silicon-based life forms also seeded from an original race?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

Humanoid beings, such as Klingons, Romulans, and Cardassians, all came from an original humanoid race ("The Chase").

Is there anything in EU works which speaks of this applying to the silicon-based life forms (Crystalline Entity, Excalbians, Horta, Microbrain, etc.)?

Comment: “Microbrain”? Isn’t that Q’s nickname for Worf?

Comment: I don't think Q explicitly used that as a nickname for Worf. He does say in "Hide and Q" (or perhaps "Encounter at Farpoint") , that Worf is a "macrohead---with a microbrain!" Later, in "Q Who," Q greets Worf by calling him "macrohead," and asking the Klingon to growl for him.

Comment: you, sir, have an [almost-perfect](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/142.txt) memory :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an interesting idea, but I haven't found any evidence for a common origin in the TV shows, films, canonical sources, or in the EU so far. Of course, proving a negative . . .

I've identified the following appearances of silicon life. There may be more.

Crystalline Entity (TNG: "Datalore", "Silicon Avatar")

Excalbians of Excalbia (TOS: "The Savage Curtain")

Horta of Janus VI (TOS: "The Devil in the Dark")

Microbrain of Velara III (TNG: "Home Soil")

Silicon-based parasite (VOY: "The Disease")

Silicon-based virus (ENT: "Observer Effect")

Silicon-based Lifeform mentioned by Hirogen (VOY: "Prey")

Possible silicon-based Lifeform Kessok (fan fiction, non-canon)

Possible silicon-based Lifeform Brikar (various novels)

**Tholians (several series)** Somehow omitted originally. Thanks, sfhq_sf!

Given the radical differences in anatomy across the group of known and possible silicon beings, it would be hard to argue that they were all seeded by one progenitor species. For instance, the Horta and the Crystalline Entity are so different in so many ways. Could some of them be related in that manner? It's possible, but I see nothing to indicate it.

Comment: You forgot the Tholians

Comment: @sfhq_sf - I knew I'd forget someone, but big miss. Thanks!